# Converting decimals to [h]:mm in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a requirement to convert decimal value to time in sql query like if input is 12.5 it should return 12h 30m, if input is 8.70 it should return 8h 42m.

Comment: `mod(8.70, 1) * 60` returns minutes ...

Comment: Do you want a string (in what format - you've shown two...), or a date, or an interval, or...?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Oracle's numtodsinterval function to achieve this.

`select numtodsinterval(to_number('12.5'), 'hour') from dual;`
Returns 0 12:30:0.0

`select numtodsinterval(to_number('8.70'), 'hour') from dual;`
Returns 0 8:42:0.0

Answer (score 0):

Maintain such conversation into a intermediate table and keep mapping to transform

Create a SP to convert and done

Answer (score 0):

If the format literally needs to be like "12h 30m" and "8h 42m", then the following could work:

```
WITH sample_data AS
(
  SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(to_number('12.5'), 'HOUR') ds_interval FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(to_number('8.70'), 'HOUR') ds_interval FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(to_number('122.25'), 'HOUR') ds_interval FROM dual
)
SELECT ( (EXTRACT(DAY FROM sample_data.ds_interval) * 24) +
         EXTRACT(HOUR FROM sample_data.ds_interval) ) || 'h ' ||
       EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM sample_data.ds_interval) || 'm ' output
  FROM sample_data;

OUTPUT         
--------
12h 30m 
8h 42m 
122h 15m
```

The format could be expanded to convert hours to days when # of hours >= 24:

```
WITH sample_data AS
(
  SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(to_number('122.25'), 'HOUR') ds_interval FROM dual
)
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM sample_data.ds_interval) || 'd ' ||
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM sample_data.ds_interval) || 'h ' ||
       EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM sample_data.ds_interval) || 'm '
  FROM sample_data;

OUTPUT         
---------
5d 2h 15m
```